# Store related files in Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

If I have an Xcode project that is version controlled and I want to keep related files together, would it be ok if I added them to a separate group in the project for as long as the files don't get included in any target? I am thinking Photoshop files and the like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical reason why you couldn't do this. However, you should be aware that if you are using Git (which is likely since it sounds like you are using the Xcode integration), the Git doesn't deal well with binary files. It will cause your repository to be bloated, as well as the fact that you won't be able to merge these files at a later date.

That said, with tools like [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) you can get around *some* of these limitations.